# How to load Angular JS directives/templates dynamically

Tags: angularjs, jsp, dynamic, angularjs-directive

I want to load angular js directives dynamically.

Consider that I have 3 directives

```
<apple data="data"/>
```

apple.html will be serving the UI for apple

```
<banana data="data"/>
```

banana.html will be serving UI for banana

```
<mango data="data"/>
```

mango.html will be serving UI for mango directive

I want to load one of these directives based on my **JSON data**

data: { fruittype: "apple": fruitObj: {"... "}}

on **UI layer**

We have a JSP that will actually hold the fruit angular tags ( i.e. either `<apple>` , `<banana>` or `<mango>` )

My question is what to write in the JSP logic   ?

Normally with the static jsp we just writing something like below;

```
<div ng-app="fruitApp">
<apple></apple>

</div>
```

Comment: What about conditional JSP?

Comment: That wont be realistic because we have about 70 fruits to support in the system :)

Comment: Then helper server function that renders necessary tag depending on the type.

Comment: I am not sure what are "helper server functions". Can you pls. elaborate more or point me to some documentation ?

Comment: Do each of these different fruit directives need to have different link functions / controller code? Or is the only thing that differs between them the contents of the markup?

Comment: Also, are you not using AngularJS in Single Page App mode? Normally, there is no need for server side rendering like JSP because AngularJS can do all of that for you. The only exception I am aware of is for SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define function in your directive scope to get templateUrl and include template into directive template  like below:

```
app.directive("fruit", function() {

  return {
    scope: {

      data: '=data',
      fruitType: '@type'

    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.getTemplate = function() {

        //path to yours templetes
        return scope.fruitType + '.html';
      }
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="getTemplate()"></div>',


  }


})
```

**Full working demo you can find here** http://plnkr.co/edit/VC6NfnYpcKFyhwgOot38?p=preview